# Diff-in-diff regression omitting variables

Tags: regression, stata

Attached is my code. I would like to know if it makes sense/am I losing necessary data points. My goal, using NIBRS data in Stata, is to create a difference in differences regression that estimates if drug-related arrests in Payette, Twin Falls, and Latah County Idaho increased after their respective neighboring state legalized marijuana. I use Blaine County, Bonneville County, and Freemont county as counterfactuals. I am using "agency_id" as a proxy for each county. When I run my, it is omitting "did_WA", "did_OR", "did_NV". Why is this?

```
clear all

   set more off

   clear

   //Creating link to my folder that contains folders with data 
   through 2011-2017
   global source = "\\netapp.bcis.bates.edu\slaski\Crime_final"


   //Refferencing my global source. Using a loop to go through the 
   year folders and turn the .csv files for incident, month, 
   suspected_drug, and offense into .dta files.
   forvalues y = 2011/2018{
    cd "$source\ID-`y'"


   //A loop within the loop this time not dealing with year, 
   but 
   rather the variables named above that we are interested in. 
       foreach i in incident month OFFENSE {
           import delim NIBRS_`i'.csv, clear
           save NIBRS_`i'.dta, replace 
           clear
       }
   }


   //A third loop this time to merge data together
   forvalues y = 2011/2018{
       cd "$source\ID-`y'"  
       use NIBRS_incident.dta
    
       //merging many to one month using month.dta
       merge m:1 nibrs_month_id using NIBRS_month.dta., force
       drop if _merge ==2
    
       // getting rid of prior merge before another 
       drop _merge
    
       //merging incident with offense.dta 
       merge 1:m incident_id using NIBRS_offense.dta, force

       save NIBRS_MERGE.dta,replace
       clear
   }

   // The new, merged data to use for the rest of the project. 
   cd "$source\ID-2011"


   use NIBRS_merge.dta


   //Final loop to append the data. Appending is "stacking" the 
   data on top of it's self.  
   forvalues y = 2011/2018{
       cd "$source\ID-`y'"
       append using NIBRS_merge.dta, force
   }


   //Saving complete appended data set
   cd "$source"
   save finalNIBRS_merge.dta, replace 

   //Dropping missing observations 
   use finalNIBRS_merge.dta
   drop if nibrs_month_id==. | month_num==. | incident_id==. 
   |data_year==.

   //Keeping only crimes related to drugs.
   //Keeping only the agency id for the counties I care about.
   keep if (offense_type_id == 16)
   keep if inlist(agency_id, 4619, 4635, 4649, 4551, 4562, 4593)


   //Colapsing the dataset to make crimes organized by month 
   number / 
   year in a combined variable.
   gen crime=1
   gen year_month = ym(data_year, month_num)
   collapse(sum) crime, by (year_month agency_id) 

   //Formating year_month to make it intelligible.
   format year_month %tm 


   gen DRUG_arrests = crime == 1






   //generating three new binary variables that indicate if the 
   arrest occurs before or after the neighboring states marijuana 
   legalization.
   gen post_legalization_WA  = year >=2012
   replace post_legalization_WA  = year >=2018 if agency_id == 
   4619

   gen post_legalization_OR = year >=2015 
   replace post_legalization_OR = year >=2018 if agency_id == 4649

   gen post_legalization_NV = year >=2016
   replace post_legalization_NV = year >=2018 if agency_id == 4635



   gen post_legalization = (year >= 2012) if inlist(agency_id, 
   4619,4635,4649)
   replace post_legalization = (year >= 2018) if inlist(agency_id, 
   4619) & (year >= 2018)
   replace post_legalization = (year >= 2015) if inlist(agency_id, 
   4649) & (year >= 2015)
   replace post_legalization = (year >= 2016) if inlist(agency_id, 
   4635) & (year >= 2016)

   gen pre_period = (year < 2012)
   gen post_period = (year >= 2012)


   // Generating a binary variable indicating if the arrest 
   occurred 
   in a county of interest or in a control county. 
   gen treatment = 1 if  agency_id== 4619 | agency_id== 4635 | 
   agency_id== 4649
   replace treatment = 0 if agency_id== 4551 | agency_id== 4562 | 
   agency_id== 4593
   gen control_vars = treatment == 0

   //Generating DID variables.
   gen did_WA = treatment * post_legalization_WA
   gen did_OR = treatment * post_legalization_OR
   gen did_NV = treatment * post_legalization_NV   

   reg DRUG_arrests did_WA did_OR did_NV control_vars i.year
```

Comment: It seems as if you've posted all your code for one project.  An optimist should think that you're doing something now quite mainstream in economics, and somebody should know about it. A pessimist will think that few people want to wade through a great chunk of code and that there aren't many people watching Stata tags here. I'd ask on Statalist and try to focus your question.

Comment: @Nick is probably right about all of these things.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this:

```
//generating three new binary variables that indicate if the 
   arrest occurs before or after the neighboring states marijuana 
   legalization.
```

but this sets all observations after 2011 to 1:

```
   gen post_legalization_WA  = year >=2012
```

and then this replaces some of those observations with 1 (which they already were):

```
   replace post_legalization_WA  = year >=2018 if agency_id == 
   4619
```

So you have no meaningful variation in your variables of interest!

you can confirm this by checking:

```
su post_legalization_WA if year>=2011
```

the same is true for the other 'post' variables.

You might want something like this instead:

```
gen post_legalization_WA  = (year >=2018 & agency_id == 
   4619)
```

This also seems like a potential mistake:

```
gen control_vars = treatment == 0
```